# How to dedistort an image without pixel loss using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel, camera-calibration

As we all know,we can use the function `cv::getOptimalNewCameraMatrix()` with alpha = 1 to get a new CameraMatrix. Then we use the function `cv::undistort()` with the new CameraMatrix can get the image after dedistortion. However, I find the image after distortion is as large as the original image and some part of the image after distortion covered by black.
So my question is ：Does this mean that the original image pixel is lost? and is there any way to avoid pixel loss or get the image whose size larger than origin image with opencv?

```
cv::Mat NewKMatrixLeft = cv::getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(KMatrixLeft,DistMatrixLeft           ,cv::Size(image.cols,image.rows),1);

cv::undistort(image, show_image, KMatrixLeft, DistMatrixLeft,NewKMatrixLeft);
```

The size of image and show_image are both 640*480,however from my point of view,the size of image after distortion should be larger than 640*480 because some part of it is meaningless.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to correct distortion, you basically have to reverse the process that caused the initial distortion. This implies that pixels are stretched and squashed along various directions to correct the distortion. In some cases, this would move the pixels away from the image edge. In OpenCV, this is handled by inserting black pixels. There is nothing wrong with this approach. You can then choose how to crop it to remove the black pixels at the edges.